# Electron frameless window not closing

Tags: node.js, electron

So i'm developing a program using Electron (11.1.1) and the button i'm using to close the program is not working
I've also downloaded [this tutorial](https://github.com/binaryfunt/electron-seamless-titlebar-tutorial) and tried to run it and it also fails to close. I'm not really sure if this is a problem with my code but here is my close function just in case.

```
const electron = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const remote = electron.remote

function closeWindow(){
 console.log("CLOSE")
 var window = remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
 window.close();
}
```

I know the button works because when I code another function with console.log it seems to print that but when i run the function above it doesn't seen to print anything (Also node intergration is set to true)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I have fixed the problem.

In Electron 10+ the tag "enableRemoteModule" is set to false by default. So to get the Remote Module to work you need to set it to true in the BrowserWindow WebPreferences. You can do this by adding
`webPreferences: {nodeIntergration: true, enableRemoteModule: true}`
into your BrowserWindow object!